# How to fix the column making whitespace and ignoring my linear gradient in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, linear-gradients

I have a Container with a linear gradient serving the purpose of being a background color for my app. When i put a Column as the child, my background only serves it's purpose in the column size. The remaining space gets a whitespace.

I have tried putting the Scaffold's background color to transparent but that turns it into a black space instead of a white space

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(32),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              stops: [0.1, 0.9],
              colors: [
                HexColor("#2a4644"),
                HexColor("#3c1630"),
              ],

            ),
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('test')
            ],
          )
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of how it looks now: http://prntscr.com/o64s1f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a Stack. The Container should occupy the whole screen width and height. Then place the Column in front of the Container.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: double.infinity,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                stops: [0.1, 0.9],
                colors: [
                  Color(0xFF2a4644),
                  Color(0xFF3c1630),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('test')
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]